# Leaflet, how to return geoJSON data from rectangle box

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have a geoJSON of linear data that displays correctly on my map. What I am looking to do is use leaflet.pm or leaflet.draw, which allows you to draw a rectangle on the map. When I draw the rectangle on the map I would like it to display the geoJSON data that is within the rectangle. Any examples on how I can do this?

Here is an example of the geoJSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "RoadSearch",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Year": 1984.0,  "Day": "Tuesday",   "Route": 79.0,  "Project": "One" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -82.08976, 40.28849 ], [ -82.08974, 40.28856 ], [ -82.08971, 40.28863 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Year": 1993.0,  "Day": "Wednesday",  "Route": 715, "Project": "Two" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -82.15866, 40.36663 ], [ -82.15803, 40.36628 ], [ -82.15757, 40.366 ], [ -82.15682, 40.36547 ], [ -82.15653, 40.36525 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: The logic I was trying to do is to use Leaflet.PM or Leaflet.Draw to crate a rectangle box and use the layer.getLatLngs(); which would return the lat and long of the four corners. After that I wanted to compare it to all the coordinates in the Geojson but I am unsure on how to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your FeatureCollection to the geoJSON layer.

```
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

What you need is to filter out certain geoJSON features :

```
var myFeatureCollection = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "RoadSearch",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Year": 1984.0,  "Day": "Happy",   "Route": 79.0,  "Project": "One" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0,1 ], [ 10,2 ] ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Year": 1984.0,  "Day": "Day",   "Route": 79.0,  "Project": "One" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 1,1  ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 10,10 ] ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Year": 1984.0,  "Day": "Sunday",   "Route": 79.0,  "Project": "One" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 2,3  ], [ 2, 20 ], [ -1,10 ] ] } }
};
```

I created a simple isInBox function that returns true if the givent coordinates are in the corresponding box (here using topleft and bottom right corners, you might have to adapt that).

```
function isInBox(topLeftCornerLat, topRightCornerLng, bottomRightCornerLat, bottomRightCornerLng, coordinates)
{
    // border not included.
    return function(coordinates) {
         return coordinates[0] > topLeftCornerLat && coordinates[0] < bottomRightCornerLat && coordinates[1] > bottomRightCornerLng && coordinates[1] < topRightCornerLng;
    }
}
```

Here i am using the isInBox function to filter the elements in box {[1,5],[6,1]}

```
var filteredGeometries = myFeatureCollection.features.filter(f => f.geometry.coordinates.some(isInBox(1,5,6,1)));

// before
console.dir(myFeatureCollection);

myFeatureCollection.features = filteredGeometries;

// after
console.dir(myFeatureCollection);
```

See the documentation : https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson

Comment: I have my GeoJSON added to the map and I can click on the linear data and it will display it's attributes. But what I want to do is select multiple lines at a time and return a list of them on my map. I thought a Rectangle box around certain linear data ,from my GeoJSON, would be the best. So how can I multi select the data with a rectangle and have it displayed?

Comment: Added some code to show you how to filter out certain elements from your feature list.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is starting to make more sense now. However I can get this to work with Lat and Longtiude that I have in my GeoJSON. Also can this be used with the Leaflet.Draw rectangle box? Finally, the console.dir is now displaying anything for me when I pass the variable. Where should I be seeing this exactly?

Comment: console.dir only works on FF and Chrome. This is just for testing. For the rest, i suggest you try to work it out and if you have another problem, then ask another question